# What is this dried animal for sale?

Tags: species-identification

I found this image on the Internet, which features an African youngster holding up an animal for sale to a potential customer sitting inside a car. It appears to be some sort of dried and disemboweled animal.

[image: ![cropped image]

What is the identity of the animal?

Comment: Looks like bat !

Comment: I'd guess it's a primate, or a big rodent.

Comment: @Dexter Definitely not a bat. It may be cane rat but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boy is holding a couple of smoked/barbecued [cane rats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_rat), also known as "grasscutters".  These are commonly hunted as bushmeat in West and Central Africa and have recently been farmed as well.

You can see some similar photos here:

- http://members.virtualtourist.com/m/p/m/178963/
- http://westafricaadventure.blogspot.com/2011_04_03_archive.html
- http://www.fionaleonard.net/2012/04/rodents-of-unusual-size.html
- http://2summers.net/2015/01/23/pop-up-travel-cane-rats-in-ghana/